# FancyBox vs TwitterBootstrap modal?

Tags: fancybox, twitter-bootstrap

For a recent project incorporated FancyBox and overall am happy with it. A friend recommended I look at the jQuery modal plugin as part of Twitter's Bootstrap framework. Has anyone used this plugin and can comment? Any pros, cons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well for pros i would have to say that since it is already included in the bootstrap you get to keep a consistent style throughout your site without the need for heavy modifications, or none at all. The bootstrap modal plugin takes advantage of CSS3 transitions to supply the effects and thus adds and extra boost in performance, coupled with its tiny size it is a very speedy solution. The bootstrap modal is painless to use and is well documented so you don't get lost.

What are the drawbacks? Well you have no control over the width and positioning of the modal, since it is positioned with CSS inside a fixed container you would have to modify the css in order to adapt it for your needs, this can get ugly when you require multiple different sized modals to load in your page. You can't vertically/horizontally center the modal on the screen without the use of heavy modifications to the js or css. You can't easily load any other media like iframes/videos/images as of yet without the need for hacks or what not. I mentioned before the added benefit and performance boots that the bootstrap modal brings by using CSS3 transitions for the effects, well this is a double edged sword since older browsers don't support those methods and thus have no presentation effects. Speaking about effects, there is only one for now, which is a slide-fade effect so not too many choices there (not a big deal but thought i note it).

I'd go with fancybox, more bang for your buck, the bootstrap modal plugin is still much to young and in future releases it will catch up to the rest.

Answer (score 5):

Pros for fancybox:

- It supports more media out of the box.

Pros for bootstrap:

- Free for commercial usage - Apache License 2.0, while Fancybox 2.x is
  CC BY-NC 3.0 Licensed.
- Already included in most of our projects.
- Pretty simple to modify and extend as we need.
- Continual and consistent updates.
- Cleaner code.  The fancybox code is full of bad practices (Browser
  Agent sniffing, using depreciated jQuery calls, buggy older IE support).
- Uses CSS heavily for the majority of the heavy lifting, making it
  smoother, smaller, and faster.
- Extremely easy to control the entire look of the modal since it's
  controlled by CSS.

Perhaps bootstrap has changed significantly since May, however, since I've been using it since August of 2012, I can say most of what Andres llich said about it being difficult to control the width/height/centering of the modal is either gone away, or more likely he just doesn't understand CSS very well.  The container is one you specify, can have an ID, and any CSS you want to "override" is as simple as specifying the ID then the appropriate class, for example:

```
#citymodal {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: -167px;
    width: 334px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

That makes our city modal 334px wide, and centered horizontally.  We could center it vertically just as easily, but this particular box is responsive (80%) to the client height and will always be larger than their viewing height (for all samples of "always" being less than 8+ 30" retina monitors stacked vertically or less).

Comment: I tried your code and it don't work. Could you make an example in jsfiddle?

Comment: Here's a quick jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E5pjU/ I updated some styles for bootstrap version 3 that weren't necessary for version 2 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd cast a vote here for Bootstrap. With Bootstrap 3, there are some nice responsive features, and I did a POC to see how I could customize the fixed width of the default Bootstrap modal. It works really well, for any content size.

http://scottpdawson.com/development/creating-a-variable-width-modal-dialog-using-bootstrap-3/

Also, you don't have to keep the title and button bars. As you'll see in this lynda.com video (available to subscribers), omitting them can get you some pretty nice full-screen photo zoom behavior.

http://www.lynda.com/course20/Bootstrap-tutorials/Updating-modals/138156/144536-4.html